# Google Cloud Platform - Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are getting such issue when deploying (uploading) code on server. please suggest any idea.

```
(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.
```

Comment: I think the error message you received there is plenty sufficient to let you know what's going on. Your health check is failing, perhaps following a 5xx error on your application.

Is your web server running? Does your application work locally?

Comment: Thank you Adam Thomason for your instant reply, yes application is working locally, also web server is running, our domain is working.

Comment: No problem. Okay, is there any output from the logs of the web server? And also the logs from any load balancers.

Comment: Yes we have changed app start time from 1500 to 3000 in yaml file, and not getting any logs.

Comment: Can you please suggest, how to get log files from server? I am checking in Activity section beside to Dashboard, but not getting any relevant info.

Comment: Perhaps this link could be of assistance? I'm not sure what you'd need to look for specifically as I'm not familiar with your application: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/activity-logs